# How to retrieve and use the setted value of a property in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** and I have the following problem trying to retrieve the value of a property and put into an XML document that I am generating.

So, I have the following situation, in my ESB flow I have defined this property named **TRANSACTION** and having **register** as value:

```
<property name="TRANSACTION" scope="default" type="STRING" value="register"/>
```

Then in my flow I am generating an XML document (it works fine), using a **payloadFactory** mediator, in this way:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <register password="$14" username="$13" xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <location>
                <wiews>$1</wiews>
                <pid>$2</pid>
                <name>$3</name>
                <address>$4</address>
                <country>$5</country>
                <lat>$6</lat>
                <lon>$7</lon>
            </location>
            <sampledoi>$8</sampledoi>
            <sampleid>$9</sampleid>
            <date>$10</date>
            <method>$11</method>
            <genus>$12</genus>
        </register>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:hold_wiews/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:hold_pid/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:hold_name/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:hold_address/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:hold_country/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:hold_lat/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:hold_lon/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:sample_doi/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:sample_id/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:date/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:method/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:genus/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:username/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:password/text()" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

That genetes an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<register username="myUserName" password="myPswd">
    <sampleid>CGN00001</sampleid>
    <genus>Hordeum2</genus>
    ...................................
    ...................................
    ...................................
```

I want use the value of my **TRANSACTION** property to create the name of the first tag of my XML document, in this:

```
<register password="$14" username="$13" xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org
```

the **register** name have to be a **$15** variable that use the **TRANSACTION** property value. I think that I can define it in some way into the **...** list but I don't know how. At this time in this list I only have value retrieved from a DSS service output, in this case I think that I have to put the value of my **TRANSACTION** property, but how?

So, is it possible to something like this:

```
<$15 password="$14" username="$13" xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org
```

to dinamically insert the tag name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that with payloadFactory but you can use a default name for your root node and just after payloadFactory mediator, add this javascript :

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().setLocalName(mc.getProperty("TRANSACTION"));
]]></script>
```

An other solution would be to use XSLT